Nginx Vs. Apache
Odd question and I know there are about 8 million sites out there about the subject. I am old school and just straight old. I remember the days of compiling Apache when the only options was to compile the extensions (mods) statically; many many moons before the world of loadable modules (for Apache or kernels or anything for that matter).
I know generally that Nginx is much faster at serving static content and is much more efficient because of its architecture. It is definitely an amazing piece of software and it is being used on many of the web servers that I manage.
What I wonder is; for a simple PHP Site (let's say a WordPress site): how well would a statically compiled Apache compare in performance to Nginx.
A site that gets very low traffic and efficiency and scalability is really not an issue.
Has anyone had any direct experience with this scenario? Is nginx still faster with fpm-php?
Also, I am really not trying to start a religious war about which web server is better. Like I said, I regularly use both but was just wondering if there is a perfect use case for statically built apache2 specific for a very finite specific websites.

I believe most of WordPress' page load time is typically spent querying databases. And nginx's big advantage over Apache is in its number of supported parallel connections (during traffic spikes), which isn't relevant for a low-traffic site. So in this specific case, I'm pretty sure Apache would have roughly the same performance as nginx.
